# Converting a [char] variable to [int] then back to [char]

Tags: c++, c, arrays, atoi, itoa

I am using Visual C 6

I am trying to convert a character array (single-quotation) into an integer, then incrementing the value by 1, then storing the result back into a different character array..

But I keep getting an unexpected value when converting back to character..

Here is my code

```
   char char_array[4];
   char_array[0] = '1';
   char_array[1] = '2';
   char_array[2] = '3';
   char_array[3] = '\0';  //Terminating character

   int my_number = atoi(char_array);  
   printf("my_number = %d" , my_number);   // output is 123

   my_number++;    // works and my_number is incremented =124
   printf("now: my_number = %d" , my_number);   // output is 124


   char result[4];  //declared to store the result

   result = itoa(my_number);  // Output is unexpected.

   printf("%c", result[0]);    // Output is  2  instead of 1
   printf("%c", result[1]);    // Output is  2
   printf("%c", result[2]);    // Output as  3   instead of 4
```

It seems that the function `itoa()` somehow knows the original value `123` and in some weird way knows that I have incremented that value.. but the addition is done to the wrong digit. Instead of adding 1 to the least significant digit, the addition is done to the most significant digit.

Comment: You have a size 3 array, and you're pretending it has size 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it **really difficult** to believe that your compiler is letting this code through:

```
char result[4];  //declared to store the result
result = itoa(my_number);  // Output is unexpected.
```

For one reason, you're attempting to reseat an array. Which shouldn't be allowed. For another, `itoa()` normally takes **three** arguments. It's prototype should look like:

```
char *itoa(int value, char * str, int base);
```

So you should be calling it as:

```
char result[4];
itoa(my_number, result, 10);
```

Or, if you'd like to use portable functions that don't have possible buffer overflows:

```
char result[4];
snprintf(result, 4, "%d", my_number);
```

Comment: ...or use standard function `snprintf(result, 4, "%d", my_number)`.

Comment: @user694733: That is absolutely worth including in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`itoa` is ***not*** a standard C library function.

You can use

```
char result[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT / 10 * 3 + 4];  // '-1', '\0', max sizeof int on my 4 byte machine
// 10 bits are roughly equal to 3 digits at decimal base, extra 4 for '-', '\0', extra digit and safe character
sprintf(result, "%d", my_number);
```

If you still want to use `itoa`, consult the documentation of this function (in library/compiler documentation)

Comment: did you mean `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` ?

Comment: No I mean `sprintf`. You can use snprintf when the buffer size is limited.

Answer (score 1):

my_number is incremented and hence if you are using `itoa()` then it will know the new value of my_number which is 124.

Check the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
   char char_array[4];
   char_array[0] = '1';
   char_array[1] = '2';
   char_array[2] = '3';
   char_array[3] = '\0';  //Terminating character

   int my_number = atoi(char_array);  
   printf("my_number = %d" , my_number);   // output is 123

   my_number++;    // works and my_number is incremented =124
   printf("now: my_number = %d" , my_number);   // output is 124


   char result[4];  //declared to store the result

   snprintf(result,4,"%d",my_number);
   printf("%c", result[0]);    
   printf("%c", result[1]);    
   printf("%c", result[2]);    
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First the itoa(my_number) maybe wrong, I only know the followed  function:

```
char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );
```

> str should be an array long enough to contain any possible value:
>   (sizeof(int)*8+1) for radix=2 i.e. 17 bytes in 16-bits platforms and
>   33 in 32-bits platforms.